# What do you call the pieces that are put underneath carport post that are on a slab and where do you get them?

Tags: repair, post, carport

I have a carport connected to my house. 
There are little footing pieces under all the post to let water run underneath ( *I am guessing* ).

A post got hit and the little piece broke and now the post is on the ground. I would like to jack the carport back up and put another piece to match the other post and keep everything as level as it was.

I do not apparently know what the actual name for this piece is and when I go to hardware stores ( *Home Depot, Lowes* ), I get looks like I am speaking a foreign language when trying to describe it. I have even showed pictures.

Comment: Can you show us one of those pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Summary of key words: post base; Simpson; stand-off; embedded

They didn't know what it was, even after showing them the picture because Home Depot people are almost never experts and often not even that knowledgeable about construction.

What you are looking for is called a **post base**. In particular, it sounds like it's a **stand-off** type which means that there is a riser at the bottom. Also, that it is likely an **embedded** type, which means that it was cast into the concrete when the concrete was poured.

Since you can't place a cast-in into cured concrete, you'll need the type that uses bolts placed into holes pre-drilled into concrete.

[**Simpson**](https://www.strongtie.com/standoffpostbases_castinplacepostbases/category) brand hardware is the most common and there are other brands. They are lots of different options. To find knowledgeable people, I suggest going to your local lumberyard or building supply, not a home improvement box giant.

Comment: https://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-ABU44Z-4x4-Adjustable-Post-Base-Zmax-Finish

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a metal base? That was poured into the concrete like a Simpson strong tie?  In any case a retrofit base will probably need to be used. Unless you can jack it up enough and shift it so a stand-off base can be anchored then put the post on that and nail it in. Simpson makes all 3 types and big box stores usually do carry them , if you just use a retrofit base I would recommend a couple of layers of shingle material to keep the post from direct contact with the concrete a stand-off base provides a separation but they need to be attached to the concrete under where the post sits, retrofit are like flanges the concrete attachment are outside the post bottom and may be easier if the tie was encased in the slab.